# What is the difference between BlobAttribute vs BlobTriggerAttribute?

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azure-blob-storage

Can anyone elaborate on the difference between `BlobAttribute` vs `BlobTriggerAttribute`?

```
   [FunctionName(nameof(Run))]
    public async Task Run(
        [BlobTrigger("container/{name}")]
        byte[] data,
        [Blob("container/{name}", FileAccess.Read)]
        byte[] data2,
        string name)
        {
                }
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-storage-blob?tabs=csharp#trigger

It seems `BlobTrigger` has all the functionality.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the doc you could find the main difference is the blob contents are provided as input with `BlobTrigger`. It means it could only read the blob, not able to write the blob.

And the the `BlobAttribute` supports binding to single blobs, blob containers, or collections of blobs and supports read and write.

Also the `BlobTrigger` could only be used to read the blob when a new or updated blob is detected. And the `Blob` binding could be used in every kind function.

Further more information about these two binding you could check the binding code: [BlobAttribute](https://github.com/Azure/azure-webjobs-sdk/blob/dev/src/Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.Storage/Blobs/BlobAttribute.cs) and [BlobTriggerAttribute](https://github.com/Azure/azure-webjobs-sdk/blob/dev/src/Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.Storage/Blobs/BlobTriggerAttribute.cs).